# Gimp file and settings dialogues open extremely slow under Windows

Tags: windows, gnome, gimp, floppy, save-as

It was pestering me for years that even though I have a pretty fast PC with SSD that every file dialogues (`Open...`, `Save as...`, `Export as...`) are brutally slow in Gimp.

The Edit \ Settings dialogue was similar.

The slowness started in Windows 7 and under Windows 8 and Windows 10 it was even worse.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it after I accidentally discovered, that an erroneous floppy drive is listed on the dialogue. Actually I don't have any floppy drives. So I disabled the `Generic Floppy Disk Drive` under `Floppy Disk Drives` in Device manager. The dialogues are opening without any delay now.

The worst thing is, that even though I googled for the issue many times, I never came across any floppy related answers only after I knew that I have to look for `floppy` keyword too.

I guess, that is a Gnome interface related issue, as that provides the file picker dialogues for the application.

Comment: It was actually here on SuperUser where the floppy trigger has been identified: https://superuser.com/questions/979504/load-dialog-disk-access-slowdown-on-windows-10/980539

Comment: The issue is in GTK up to 2.24. The most recent GIMP 2.10.24 ships with a fixed GTK and doesn't have that issue anymore. See the corresponding issue report https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/913 for details.

Comment: Great news, thanks, so now updating is also a solution :)